# Adding new resources directory into config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, twig, twig-extension

After my recent question and answer(which is working well), I have created my own template:

```
 {% extends "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" %}
{% block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' combobox input-large form-control')|trim}) %}
    {{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock %}
```

First it was under the directory of...

```
..\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\form_combo_layout.html.twig
```

However, since there are other templates like the one that I extended from bootstrap, I didnt want my 'combobox'component override with original bootstrap template since they are using exactly same folder path which is

```
..\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\"template name"
```

and there was no problem on config.yml when I was calling as...

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes: ['Form/form_errors.html.twig']
    form:                 
         resources: ['form_combo_layout.html.twig']
```

However, because of the overriding of similar components I put into different file under "Resources" which is

```
..\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\templates\form_combo_layout.html.twig
```

and depend on that I wanted to modify the path in my config.yml as...

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes: ['Form/form_errors.html.twig']
    form:
         resources: ['../Resources/templates/form_combo_layout.html.twig']
```

at the end... I faced with an error on localhost in related page which is...

```
Unable to find template "../Resources/templates/form_combo_layout.html.twig" in base.html.twig at line 23.
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Loader
1 linked Exception: RuntimeException »
```

Eventhough, file path and file exists.

some bulleye help would be appreciated!!!!

PS:It is written in cookbook that we cannot use parameters to build paths in imports dynamically..

```
imports:
    - { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/parameters.yml" }
```

this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found solution which is easy like hell....
since resources path requests an array form with a "directory path" parameter it should be

```
resources: ['templates/form_combo_layout.html.twig']
```